# I receive "This request requires buffering data to succeed" exception while CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStream from a HttpPostedFile

Tags: azure-blob-storage, httppostedfile

Stream Code

```
var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
if (httpRequest.Files.Count == 1)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = httpRequest.Files[0];

    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(BaseService.BlobConnection));
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(documentType.Description);
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

    blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = file.ContentType;
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(file.InputStream, file.ContentLength);
}
```

I am using two files to test with the first is a docx file that is only 12.3KB and a pdf that is 1.47MB.  The docx file uploads without issue, the pdf is what generates the error.

I have only found two items that attempt to explain what is going on and I really can't make heads or tails out of them. [Item 1](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2855735) & [Item 2](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/908573)

I was able to use the following code, using byte data to upload without error but when I attempted to download either file they are corrupted.

```
var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
if (httpRequest.Files.Count == 1)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = httpRequest.Files[0];
    byte[] buffer = null;
    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
    { buffer = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength); }

    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(BaseService.BlobConnection));
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(documentType.Description);
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

    blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = file.ContentType;
    blockBlob.UploadFromByteArray(buffer, 0, file.ContentLength);
}
```

ANSWERED:
The issue was in my Storage Connection string I had is selected to use HTTP connections instead of HTTPS (it's recommended for a reason). I'm not sure what that has to do with buffering to succeed, but it solved the issue and I'm now able to store uploaded files into blob storage.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was in my Storage Connection string I had is selected to use HTTP connections instead of HTTPS (it's recommended for a reason).  I'm not sure what that has to do with buffering to succeed, but it solved the issue and I'm now able to store uploaded files into blob storage.